# Como cambiar la mascara de formato en mi aplicacion en oracle apex

Tags: oracle, apex

Estoy trabajando una aplicacion con oracle apex vesion 22, tengo un formulario en donde se insertar algunos precios, el cliente me esta solicitando que el campo acepte decimales despues del punto (.) y no despues de la coma (,) quisiera saber en que parte de la aplicacion puedo editar el separador de decimales para cambiarlo a punto (.). Si me pueden ayudar lo agradeceria muchisimo.

Comment: en la pestana format mask, seleccionas el campo y el panel de la derecha segunda pestana

Answer (score 2):

Eso tiene que ver con el TimeZone de la aplicación, lo puedes modificar justo después de ingresar al modo desarrollo de la aplicación en la opción "editar definición de aplicación" y luego en la pestaña de globalización por default muchas veces toma el NLS de la base de datos y si esta en un servicio de nube por ejemplo te va a tomar los valores de la configuración de este.
Puedes probar con spanish(United States)(es-us)

[image: Cambio de idioma]